# how to set global environment variable in gitLab ci/cd pipeline?

Tags: gradle, gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I have a gradle project in which a file (setting.gradle) which requires artifactory user and artifactory password to download all dependencies.
So for local we put these values in gradle.propeties file and it works well.
So I put these artifactory user and artifactory password in gitlab variable (setting -> CI/CD -> variable-> Add variable). But now my setting.gradle unable to fetch these value.
After some research I found out that these variable are not gobal. Can some one help me how put these value as gobal or let me know if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your gradle project reads variables only from gradle.properties then you can append those variables in your file

```
script:
- 'echo variable_1= $variable_1 >> gradle.properties'
- 'echo variable_2= $variable_2 >> gradle.properties'
```